# How do I enable CacheMode in ContentDialog in UWP C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

I'm developing an UWP app with a ContentDialog which has a `TextBox`. I want to enable caching for the `ContentDialog` so that the state of the ContentDialog does not change even after closing the dialog.

In other words, if an user enter their name in the above mentioned `TextBox`. The name should not be reset even after closing the dialog. Again after reopening the dialog, the user's name should be there in the TextBox.

Thanks in Advance.,

Comment: You can keep the ContentDialog's values in your ViewModel.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not using MVVM for this project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I enable CacheMode in ContentDialog in UWP C#?

To achieve this behavior, please make sure that you are not creating a new `ContentDialog` every time when you are trying to show a `ContentDialog`. As long as you are always calling the same `ContentDialog` instance and you are not resetting the values manually, the status of the `ContentDialog` won't be changed.

For example, I created a `ContentDialog` in XAML like this:

```
 <ContentDialog x:Name="MyDialog"
                   Width="500" 
                   PrimaryButtonText="OK"
                   SecondaryButtonText="Cancel" >
        <StackPanel Height="Auto" Width="450" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtHotlistMsg" Text="Title"/>
            <ToggleButton Content="Check" IsChecked="False"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="ttBox" PlaceholderText="Type something"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ContentDialog>
```

If I call the `MyDialog.ShowAsync()` method in the code-behind, type something in the `TextBox` or checked the `ToggleButton` and then close the button with the OK button. The status of them won't be changed when you open the `ContentDialog` again.